# json_encode still failing after using utf8_encode

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a rather large array I'm trying to convert into a json object with php's json_encode function. This array consists of mostly URL's and is typically 3-10mb when I print_r to a file. It typically works 95% of the time however some special characters are sneaking in there that are causing JSON_encode to fail. So I thought this code below would take care of that but I'm still getting JSON_ERROR_UTF8 returned.

```
array_walk_recursive($job_return_data, function(&$item, &$key){
    $item = utf8_encode($item); $key = utf8_encode($key);
});

$job_return_data_json = json_encode($job_return_data);
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be failing still?

Comment: check below code hope it will help you.

Comment: have you check below answer, It's work?

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I even tried putting htmlspecialchars() in as another post suggested. I've got it working now though, I'm just putting every URL though filter_var($link_to_check, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($input));
$json = json_decode($input);
```

Hope it help you.